# Al seleccionar una fecha en mi input date que automaticamente traiga año y mes en otro boton php javascript

Tags: php, javascript

como puedo hacer para sacar el año y el mes al seleccionar la fecha de mi input date.

Tengo el siguiente código:

Aqui selecciono mi fecha de mi input date

```
Seleccione Fecha:<br>

<input type="date" name="fecha_des" id="fecha_des">
```

Ahora como hago para que apenas seleccione la fecha en otro input aparte me traiga el año y el mes, ejemplo:

Selecciono: 05/03/2020

Y que en otro input coloque: 2020-03

Y que adiconalmente en otro input coloque solo el nombre del mes ejemplo: MAR

Se puede hacer con Javascript y PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto puede servir. Todo lo realice desde Javascript. Todo desde lado del cliente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_des" id="fecha_des">
        <input type="text" name="fecha_anio" id="fecha_anio">
        <input type="text" name="fecha_mes" id="fecha_mes">
    </body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fecha_des').change(function () {
                extraer = $('#fecha_des').val();
                $fechaAnio = extraer.substring(0, 7);
                $fechaMes = parseInt(extraer.substring(5, 7));

                $('#fecha_anio').val($fechaAnio);

                var mesesLetra = ["ENE", "FEB", "MAR", "ABR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DIC"];
                var mesLetra = mesesLetra[$fechaMes - 1];

                $('#fecha_mes').val(mesLetra);
            });
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Isai Maldonado excelente tu respuesta muchas gracias por tu ayuda me funciono perfectamente como quería. saludo y bendiciones.